# How to disable a specific IBM XL C++ compiler warning?

Tags: c++, pragma, suppress-warnings, xlc

Given tmp.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma report(disable, CCN8826)

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const char * hi = "hi\n";
    printf(hi);

    return 0;
}
```

Despite I use `#pragma report` that is supposed to suppress the warning, I still get:

```
bash-3.1$ xlC -qformat=all tmp.cpp
"tmp.cpp", line 8.12: 1540-2826 (W) The format string is not a string literal 
and format arguments are not given.
```

How do I get rid of that warning?

The error message numbers are [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.cbcdg01/cbcdg17003.htm) and the #pragma report description is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/pragma.htm).
My compiler is IBM XL C/C++ Advanced Edition for Blue Gene/P, V9.0

Comment: The message identifier in your `#pragma` statement and the compiler warning do not match. Maybe you should be using `#pragma report(disable, CCN2826)` instead?

Comment: Well you explicitly told it to turn on all format diagnostic messages...

Comment: @Praetorian: actually CCN8826 is the compiler message identifier per the user manual.

Comment: @sixlettervariables You wrote `CNN8826` and the question contains `CCN8826`, another discrepancy :). Anyway, I was just taking a potshot; I've never used this compiler.

Comment: @Praetorian as sixlettervariables mentioned the compiler message identifier is taken from the only manual which I have found to mention this error (http://ibm.co/SYEOrr). It is however the manual for the other IBM compiler. I could not find any references to "The format string is not a string literal ..." in the original reference here: http://ibm.co/12pfMof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it doesn't directly answer your question but you could presumably avoid the warning by changing your code to

```
printf("%s", hi);
```

In case you have:

```
void f(char * s) { printf(s); }
```

you can modify it as:

```
void f(char * s) { printf("%s", s); }
```

to get rid of the warning.

EDIT: An easy, slightly limited, probably nasty way of dealing with your new issue would be

```
char buf[1024];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s %s", "bloody", "warning");
fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
```

It may be possible to generalise this to something like the following (untested!)

```
my_printf(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char buf[1024];
    vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, ap);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
}
```

Comment: In this particular case it would help, but this is only an example to make it clear what I wanted to do. The original code looks conceptually like that: `void function(char * s) { fprintf(stderr, s); }`

Comment: @mezhaka The same type of workaround could apply - `void function(char * s) { fprintf(stderr, "%s", s); }`

Comment: That is so smart! I envy you came up with this! I am going to edit and accept you answer.

Comment: Heck, I've bumped into this again, I still cannot do a this: `char* format = "%s %s"; printf(format, "bloody", "warning");`. I cannot use the `printf("%s", s)` trick here...

Comment: I've updated my answer with a workaround for this new format and a speculative approach for a more general solution.  Just in case you've made recent progress with it, disabling the warning would be neater than either of my suggestions :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Nope, still do not know how to disable it, but in a couple of weeks I am going to meet some guys from IBM, who might shred light on this annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

As the message indicates, its message identifier is 1540-2826, therefore change the #pragma report to:

#pragma report(disable, "1540-2826")

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the compiler not to generate this warning (for any code, not just the line in question) by passing the flag `-qsuppress=1540-2826`.

To suppress multiple warnings, separate the codes with a semicolon e.g. `-qsuppress=1540-2826:1540-0809`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message IDs produced by IBM XL C++ depend on the operating system.  On z/OS the message IDs look like CCN8826, but elsewhere they look like 1540-2826.

On z/OS UNIX System Services, compiling your code using `xlc++ tmp.cpp` yields no warnings or errors.  In any case, adding

```
-qsuppress=CCN8826
```

to the xlc++ command line ought to do the trick there if that error does show up.  Based on Josh Milthorpe's answer,

```
-qsuppress=1540-2826
```

should work on operating systems where that message ID format is used.

Note that **not all messages can be suppressed**, so if you get a complaint about the message you're trying to suppress then that may be because that particular message cannot be suppressed, even if you are using the correct format for specifying a message to suppress.

The [z/OS V2R2 XL C/C++ Messages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbcux01/suppress.htm) document suggests that only message numbers 3000 through 4399 (for C), and 5001 through 6999 and 7500 through 8999 (for C++) can be suppressed.  If I specify `-qsuppress=CCN1142` on z/OS UNIX System Services for a source file that yields message CCN1142 then I get a complaint about 'Unrecognized value "CCN1142" specified with option "SUPPRESS".' and message CCN1142 continues to be reported.  `-qsuppress=CCN8826` produces no complaint.