# How to disable a specific warning of IBM xl C++ compiler via compiler commandline?

Tags: c++, suppress-warnings, xlc

I get compiler message/information

```
1500-030: (I) INFORMATION: ... Additional optimization may be attained by recompiling and specifying MAXMEM option with a value greater than 8192.
```

and it cannot be turned off by

```
#pragma report(disable, "1500-030")
```

as suggested by question [How to disable a specific IBM XL C++ compiler warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863815/how-to-disable-a-specific-ibm-xl-c-compiler-warning)

Comment: It is the first question I have encountered that is related to IBM mainframe. By the way it is me who wrote CTRACE record filtering for the IBM NFS Server using PL/X.: instead of the programmer who failed the project.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What OS is xlc running on?

Try

```
-qsuppress=1500-030
```

Or

```
-w
```

Comment: the operating system is AIX and qsuppress did the trick. thanks!